# How to remove black border when GUI is selected?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add an `Entry` widget to a `Frame` with a `Scrollbar`. When I click on the GUI, a black border appears:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                              tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)
        self.addEntry()

    def addEntry(self):
        self.entryVariable = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.frame,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')

        self.entryVariable.set(u"")
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, tk.END)

    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

How to remove this black border that appears when GUI is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the border of your widgets (for example of a `Text` widget) set the `highlightthickness` attribute to `0`.

Here, you have a working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, highlightthickness=0)
        self.text.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

root = tk.Tk()
Example(root).pack(expand=1, fill='both')
root.mainloop()
```